# Load Json from Complicated Csv/DataFrame, retain dtypes for MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas

I am trying to build at json tree for a queryable MongoDB from some disparate csv/excel files. The data is often incomplete and linked by a subject id.

Example data below:

```
subid,firstvisit,name,contact,dob,gender,visitdate1,age,visitcategory,samplenumber,label_on_sample,completed_by
    1,12/31/11,Bob,,12/31/00,Male,,,,,,
    1,,,,,,12/31/15,17,Baseline Visit,,,
    1,,,,,,12/31/16,18,Follow Up Visit,,,
    1,,,,,,12/31/17,18,Follow Up Visit,,,
    1,,,,12/31/00,Male,,17,,XXX123,1,Sally
    2,1/1/12,,,1/1/01,Female,,,,,,
    2,,,,,,1/1/11,10,Baseline Visit,,,
    2,,,,,,1/1/12,11,Follow Up Visit,,,
    2,,,,,,1/1/13,12,Follow Up Visit,,,
    2,,,,,,1/1/14,13,Follow Up Visit,,,
    2,,,,,,1/1/15,14,Follow Up Visit,,,
    2,,,,1/1/01,Female,,15,,YYY456,2,
    2,,,,1/1/01,Female,,15,,ZZZ789,2,Sally'
```

I'd like the output to look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "subject_id": "1",
        "name": "Bob",
        "dob": "12/31/00",
        "gender": "Male",
        "visits": {
            "12/31/15": {
                "age": "17",
                "visit_category": "Baseline Visit"
            },
            "12/31/16": {
                "age": "18",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            },
            "12/31/17": {
                "age": "18",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            }
        },
        "samples": {
            "XXX123": {
                "completed_by": "Sally",
                "label_on_sample": "1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "subject_id": "2",
        "name": null,
        "dob": "1/1/01",
        "gender": "Female",
        "visits": {
            "1/1/11": {
                "age": "10",
                "visit_category": "Baseline Visit"
            },
            "1/1/12": {
                "age": "11",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            },
            "1/1/13": {
                "age": "12",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            },
            "1/1/14": {
                "age": "13",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            },
            "1/1/15": {
                "age": "14",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            }
        },
        "samples": {
            "YYY456": {
                "completed_by": null,
                "label_on_sample": "2"
            },
            "ZZZ789": {
                "completed_by": "Sally",
                "label_on_sample": "2"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I have a program that puts all of this into the right structure, but unfortunately because it uses csv's DictReader, it seems all variables are entered in as strings, making it difficult to query in meaningful ways. This code is below:

```
def solution(csv_filename):
    by_subject_id = defaultdict(lambda: {
        'name': None,
        'dob': None,
        'gender': None,
        'visits': {},
        'samples': {}
    })

    with open(csv_filename) as f:
        dict_reader = DictReader(f)
        for row in dict_reader:
            non_empty = {k: v for k, v in row.items() if v}
            subject_id = non_empty['subid']  # must have to group by
            first_visit = non_empty.get('firstvisit')  # optional
            sample = non_empty.get('samplenumber')  # optional
            visit = non_empty.get('visitdate1')  # optional

            if first_visit:
                by_subject_id[subject_id].update({
                    'name': non_empty.get('name'),
                    'dob': non_empty.get('dob'),
                    'gender': non_empty.get('gender')
                })
            elif visit:
                by_subject_id[subject_id]['visits'][visit] = {
                    'age': non_empty.get('age'),
                    'visit_category': non_empty.get('visitcategory')
                }
            elif sample:
                by_subject_id[subject_id]['samples'][sample] = {
                    'completed_by': non_empty.get('completed_by'),
                    'label_on_sample': non_empty.get('label_on_sample')
                }
    return [{'subject_id': k, **v} for k, v in by_subject_id.items()]
```

What would be the best way to solve this issue? Could I convert this to work for a dataframe and hopefully retain the dtypes?

Thanks so much for any advice. New to Mongo, just trying to get something that works.

Comment: if I understand the problem, e.g. `"subject_id": "1"`, you would like better `"subject_id": 1` where 1 is an integer instead of a string? if yes you can probably do in your code `'subject_id': int(k)` and same idea for other values

Comment: @Ben.T That works for 'subject_id' but not the other fields as it breaks upon encountering the many NaN's. Thanks for the help. It's one part solved, but the greater problem remains.

Comment: which label you want to change beside `subject_id`? I guess `age` and `label_on_sample` to `int` but do you need to convert date like `dob` to datetime object?

Comment: Ideally. All the data was assigned a type in the dataframe during the cleaning and processing of it. It'd be great to retain those types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is not the best solution, but using pandas might be helpfull for keeping type of values, I did not look at the efficiency of the code, justthe part on reading the csv file but you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
def solution(csv_filename):
    by_subject_id = defaultdict(lambda: {
        .
        .
    })

    df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename).fillna('')
    for row in df .iterrows():
        non_empty = {k: v for k, v in row[1].iteritems() if  v != ''}
        subject_id = non_empty['subid']  # must have to group by
        .
        .
        .
```

I try to keep the fews lines changeed, everything else is the same. Ultimately, if you can directly have as parameter your cleaned DF instead of reading the csv file it would be better. Otherwise, you can add `dtype=` in read_csv() such as:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename,dtype={'subid':int, 'age':int}).fillna('')
```

add any type you want to have.

I hope it helps you

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much. There are still a few problems here and there with date columns being returned a strings instead of date objects, but this fixes so much. Thanks again!

Comment: @jester_in_yellow I don't know MongoDB, but if you want date objects, you can try to add in dtype `{'dob':pd.datetime}` (never try so not sure it works) or before getting in your loop, `df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dob'])` but if MongoDB does not recognize python datetime object, it is not necessary